# Android backup file dont exracted with Android Backup Extractor

Tags: backup

with this [tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011811) i want extract my backup file but encountered with this error(error message is attached as image). What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: For unknown reason, it seems something is either corrupted/encrypted. The error tells you that the app requires number input, but processing garbled string instead. Also, could you clarify which step produced this? I couldn't find the one with `java -jar abe.jar info <backup_file>`.

Comment: The backup file is made with "Android System Recovery". The file don't made with ADB command line. Is there more for clarify?

Comment: Indeed the backup file is made in Android System Recovery when i was locked out of my android (Huawei Y511) after forgetting the pattern. Do for extract the backup file the pattern is required???

Comment: more: 
I was locked out of my android after forgotten phone pattern. i get to Android System Recovery and make a backup from my phone "user_data_*.backup". How i try open the backup file on my PC with 
http://adbextractor.sourceforge.net/ 
but: 
this error eccured: 
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98234/android-backup-file-dont-exracted-with-android-backup-extractor 
Do for extracting file backup "phone pattern" is required?

Comment: Phone pattern is not required, but when doing the backup, did you provide a password? Also, I'm not sure if storage encryption is related or not (though you didn't mention this here)

Comment: I didn't provide a password. I don't understand this statement: "Also, I'm not sure if storage encryption is related or not (though you didn't mention this here)"